# While loop augments wanted result?

Tags: java, math, while-loop

This method finds the smallest number which can be divided by all numbers 1-10 using a while loop. However, if I set the system to print +i, the output is the correct answer +1. What's wrong with this code?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int i=11;
int counter=0;
    while(counter<10){

        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++){
            if((i%j)!=0) {
                counter=0;
                break;
            }
            else counter++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("The number is: "+i);


}
```

Comment: Try running your code under a debugger and watch how the values of variables change during code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because 'i++' increments i by 1 before the loop is exited. So, if the answer is 10, then before the loop exits, 'i++' changes it to 11. So, you can either choose to print 'i-1' to get the correct answer **or** you can write the code in such a way that when the right answer is found, 'i++' does not get executed.

You can do this -

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int i=11;
int counter=0;
    while(counter<10){

        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++){
            if((i%j)!=0) {
                counter=0;
                break;
            }
            else counter++;
        }
        if(counter!=10)    //this change
        {
          i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The number is: "+i);
}
```

Or you can do this

```
System.out.println("The number is : " + (i-1));
```